# java split confusing space character

Tags: java, regex, split, space

I am splitting a string which contains a filename from a windows system. The string uses the ascii FS to separate the filename from other information

e.g. filename.jpgFSotherInformationFSanotherPartOfInformation

Here some example code:

```
String fs = new String(new byte[]{(byte)32}); 
String information ="filename (copy).jpg"+fs+"otherInformation"; 
String[] parts = information.split(fs);
```

Why does split confuse the space-separator with the ascii-FS?

Should I use a different function that split? Pattern.quote(fs) does help either... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because FS is not ascii value 32.

http://bestofthisweb.com/blogs/tag/ascii-table/

The `FS` is character 28, but this control character should not be used in file names, only for some rare binary file formats (I don't know of one which uses it anymore)

The space character is 32 which is why it looks the same the split, because it is.

For a simple field seperator, I suggest you use ',' or '\t' which can be easily read as text or using a spreadsheet package.

I would suggest stepping through the code in a debugger so you can see what you program is doing.

Comment: That explain everything. I need the fs for character that isn'T used in filenames, so fs is perfect.

Comment: On Linux, every character is allowed in filenames, except binary zero `\0` and the path separator slash `/`.

Comment: @Hans-Wurscht, I would say TB `\t` is better as its easier to read. e.g. you can load the data into Excel or Open Office. As @user unknown points out, either FS or TB can be in a file name on UNIX, so if you are really worried about it I would either use `\0` or a different format. e.g. have the length of each field before the field. e.g. writeUTF()/readUTF() This allows any character in a field.

Comment: A `\t` or any other white space character is **very annoying in filenames,** because it makes them harder to work with from the command line.

Comment: @tchrist, And files like `-i`. In my Uni days I used to have directories like `...` and `.. ` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've initialized `fs` with a space (in a rather complicated way). The following is equal and shows your problem:

```
String fs = " "; 
String information ="filename (copy).jpg"+fs+"otherInformation"; 
String[] parts = information.split(fs);
```

The ascii char `FS` has the number `0x1C`, so this should work properly:

```
String fs = "\u001C"; 
String information ="filename (copy).jpg"+fs+"otherInformation"; 
String[] parts = information.split(fs);
```

---

**Background information**

> The file separator FS is an interesting control code, as it gives us insight in the way that computer technology was organized in the sixties. We are now used to random access media like RAM and magnetic disks, but when the ASCII standard was defined, most data was serial. I am not only talking about serial communications, but also about serial storage like punch cards, paper tape and magnetic tapes. In such a situation it is clearly efficient to have a single control code to signal the separation of two files. The FS was defined for this purpose. [(source)](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/ascii-characters.html)

The `FS` was invented to separate real *files* and not *filenames* in a hierarchical file directory. Technically, yes, you can use it, but it has a different meaning.

Comment: @Peter - I'm still an old-fashioned hex guy if it comes to ascii codes ;)

Comment: I remember programming all my text in hex for two years before I got a compiler on my 8086 ;) how about `char fs = 0x1C;`

Comment: @Peter - ah, c'mon - everyone knows that 0x1c is a literal an 0x1c is equal to 28 - just wanted to add a tiny little bit of extra knowledge, showing how to use bytes in String literals ;)

Comment: If your knowledge is tiny at 25.9k, pitty me on 25.2k ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D, if you really were old-fashioned, you’d be using be using 034 for the INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR a.k.a. FS character. :)

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse FS is Ascii values 28

Ascii value 32 is `space`

Answer (score 0):

Split's parameter is actually a regular expression, have you tried

```
String[] parts = information.split("\\x20");
```

Or even

```
String[] parts = information.split("\\s");
```